# How to get probability of spam rather than classification

Tags: machine-learning

I am building a tool to calculate a probability of a text review to be fake(spam) or real.

I have an annotated dataset of reviews marked as spam or nonspam. I have used svm to build a classifier, but that only gives me classification of an input document as spam or nonspam. Whereas, I want a tool that will give me a number between 0 and 1 representing probability of the document being spam. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a continuous-valued score (rather than an explicit probability), you can just use the distance to the hyperplane from the SVM. This is a standard measure of confidence, which you can see as how far "into" the class the point is.

If you want to actually use the classifications as part of a broader probabilistic model, where you need something with a genuine probability interpretation, you could use one of the methods for converting SVM scores into probabilities, but these are somewhat retrofit and don't have great theoretical underpinnings. Instead, I'd suggest you take a look at the [logistic regression classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), sometimes known as Maximum Entropy, for a robust probabilistic alternative. This has the benefits of a discriminative model like SVM but with a natural and inherent probabilistic underpinning.

Comment: Good answer in your second paragraph but regarding the first paragraph - distance from the hyperplane is a poor substitute for probability.  First, distance from the hyperplane doesn't have a straightforward interpretation.  What does a distance of 2.693 from an N-dimensional hyperplane mean to a user? Second, probability of correct classification isn't linear in distance from the hyperplane so comparing two distances doesn't indicate how much more probable one classification is than another.  Lastly, the distance is unbounded, whereas the questioner specifically wants a score between 0 and 1.

Comment: I quite agree - distance to the hyperplane isn't a substitute for probability, and I wouldn't advise giving an end user this score. I think what's being requested is posterior probability of class membership, however, not probability of correct classification. I guess what my answer should say is, if you want a real-valued confidence, you can use the distance (this should suffice for a lot of stuff that's not an actual probability model), and if you want a probability you should consider whether you want to use an SVM at all, as they are by design not probabilistic.

Comment: Oops.  I meant "probability of spam".  Not "probability of correct classification".

Comment: I used the distance metric, but did not get good results with this. I agree with Ben that SVM is probably not suited for my application. I am now moving to Bayesian models, and that is giving better probabilities on my test data.

Comment: This is a great discussion. Is there any textbook or other reference that clearly identifies which classifiers can return a posterior probability and which cannot? For example, I was banging my head with a C4.5 tree trying to get a posterior probability (because Weka has a function to get this probability from any classifier), but I eventually realized C4.5 does not calculate posterior probability well.

Comment: Anything explicitly formulated probabilistically will give you a probability (or sometimes, something proportional to a probability). That's Bayesian methods, including the Naive Bayes classifier as the most simple example, and logistic regression/maxent as its discriminative counterpart. Generalising to lots of variables, things formulated as graphical models return probabilities---so that's MRFs and CRFs, as well as directed graphical models.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own, why not plug into [akismet](http://www.akismet.com)? Spam detection is Bayesian and performs better the more data you give it.

Comment: Thanks, but the tool I am trying to build will be used for detecting spam in reviews written for Yelp, Amazon etc. I have developed the features and it works well. But, I need probabilities, which I can further use in another algorithm. If I get just a binary classification, then it will not be helpful.

Comment: Didn't realise you were actually rather far along in your design... If you're interested, take a look at the source code of [spamassassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the probability with a SVM. Take a look at libsvm (-b parameter).